# EF Code First EntityType has no key defined even if Annotation is added

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Trying to do Migrations but after executing add-migration command,
it says that:

```
EntityType 'City' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

THis is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CodeFirstPrimer.Models.NHL
{
    public class City
    {  
        [Key]
        public int CityId;
        public String CityName;
        public int Population;

    }
}
```

I had already put an annotation on CityId.

Anyone has hint where/what could possibly is wrong?

Comment: try adding empty get and set methods to the properties. also, I do believe a parameterless constructor is necessary for EF to pick up fields.

Comment: cool it works!.. but why it need to have those get and set methods? I was trying to add the get and set in my DBcontext in which I put `public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }`

Comment: this is the get and set for your dbset, not for your entities. I think based on these functions EF picks up the properties through reflection.

Comment: You don't need the attribute if you call it cityId since it follows the default convention.

Comment: EF doesn't support mapping member variables, only properties.